# how change table names in json array codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

Sorry I'm not sure if my question is correct. My problem is I'm trying to change the table names in json format that are produced by calling a function in codeigniter.  Is this possible?

I have 2 items on my database to begin with....

This Json is produced by the controller & model below:

```
{

"data": [
   {
    "real_id": "1"
   },
   {
     "real_id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I have this on my controller:

```
//-----CONTROLLER:

$messages = $this->message_model->get_messages();

if(count($messages) > 0){
  

  $this->response(array(
    "data" => $messages
  ) );
  
}
```

And my model:

```
// Model 
public function get_messages(){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("myDataBase");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
     
    }
```

If possible, I wanted to change the "real_id" and make it like "FAKE_id" like the example below:

```
{
   
    "data": [
       {
        "FAKE_id": "1"
       },
       {
         "FAKE_id": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried something like this but it only shows 1 (one) item.

```
...
if(count($messages) > 0){
      foreach ($messages as $data) {
         $id =  $data->real_id;
         $arr = array(
          "FAKE_id" => $id
           ); 
        }
      $result = $arr;
 
      $this->response(array(
       
        "data" => $messages
      ) );
      
    }
```

The output of that is this which is wrong because only one is displaying:

```
{
  
    "data": [
       {
        "FAKE_id": "2"
       },
       
      ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are overwriting `$arr` every iteration of foreach loop. Try `$arr[] = array(....`

Comment: you're right @charlietfl this works too!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query just change the column names instead of selecting the default ones like so:

```
$this->db->select("real_id AS fake_id");
$this->db->from("myDataBase");
$query = $this->db->get();
```